# Need to show scatter chart in front of line chart

Tags: lightningchart

I need to show scatter chart points on top of the point of line chart so, It would be visible in a zoom-out case. I've tried to render scatter chart before a point line chart but It's not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the order of creating series passes on to actual rendering order. So, to show scatter over line, you would first make the line series and then point series.

That said, we are aware that there are some bugs with some series types regarding this.

The below snippet seems to behave like expected.

```js
const {
    lightningChart,
    SolidFill,
    ColorRGBA
} = lcjs

const chart = lightningChart().ChartXY()

const line = chart.addLineSeries()
    .setStrokeStyle(stroke => stroke.setThickness(5))
    .addArrayY([0,5,0,5,0])

const scatter = chart.addPointSeries()
    .setPointFillStyle(new SolidFill({color: ColorRGBA(255,0,0)}))
    .addArrayY([0,5,0,5,0])
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.4.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if the graph is point line series instead of line series? It'll be an overlapping situation, right? how can I show scatter point over pointing series graph? I've tried to render scatter graph after point line series but It seems like not working for me.

Comment: I believe point line series works just the same as line series in the example as in the scatter points would be shown above the points as well as lines of the point line series.

Comment: If you have some code snippet of this, which is not working for you then please share it in the question.